# Mapping a network drive only when connected to a Domain

Tags: batch-file, dns, windows-7-x64, network-drive, group-policy

I have looked around a bit, and I haven't found a solution that exactly fits my needs. I have a Laptop that I use for work, and for personal use at home. At work, we are operating on a Domain, and have several Network Storage locations that I use often. So i decided that I want to Map these drives. However, I do not want to get popup messages nor see that these drives are disconnected when I am at home, and there is no connection to these servers. Is there a built in way to accomplish this task in windows 7, or am I going to need to resort to a start up script. If I need a script, how can I check to see if the computer is connected to a Domain, and then map drives based on that option. If a script is required, I would prefer to use a .bat file. Another route that would be achievable is doing this through group policy if someone can direct me as to how to push certain mapped drives to specific users.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, I believe if value of the Windows variable USERDOMAIN is equal to the value of COMPUTERNAME then your host is not in a domain

```
If %USERDOMAIN% <> %COMPUTERNAME% SET indomain="y"
```

Alternatively, you can 'hack' it by trying to do something like a DIR of a folder like WINDOWS on a computer that's part of the domain. If you get denied then you're not part of the domain.